# how to upcast object array to another type of object array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, casting

I want to upcast object array to different array of different object type like below

object[] objects; // assuming that it is non-empty

CLassA[] newObjects = objects as ClassA[]; // assuming that object to ClassA is valid upcasting

is there any way other than upcasting each element individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

newObjects = objects.Select(eachObject => (ClassA)eachObject).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

As [this post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/07/09/want-generic-variance-in-c-3-or-even-c-2-no-problem.aspx) suggests, you may be able to do the following trick (untested):

```
newObjects = (ClassA[])(object)objects;
```

Note that in C# 4.0 you won't need to cast, you will be able to directly assign `newObjects = objects`.

Answer (score 2):

Or I guess you could try something like this for even shorter syntax:

```
newObjects = objects.Cast<ClassA>().ToArray();
```